# How to use python lib pyautogui controller role of World Of Warcraft?

Tags: python, pyautogui, world-of-warcraft

I used pyautogui to simulate rotation angle in World Of Warcraft

I try to press the "right button of the mouse " + "move the mouse" distance, it seems that the camera cannot be rotated, and it has not been resolved so far T.T

(I am not sure , if there is a demo for this)

So I use keyDown('right') + keyUp('left') to rotate the camera

I encountered a problem, I learned that it takes 2s to rotate a circle of 360,

So when I calculate the angle

```
pyautogui. keyDown('right')

press_time = ange * (360/ 2000) / 1000

time. sleep(press_time)

pyautogui. keyDown('up')
```

However, I found that the angle is actually too large. It seems that the angle of rotation is greater than 360 degrees by pressing the right 2s. Can someone help me?

However, I found that the angle is actually too large. It seems that the angle of rotation is greater than 360 degrees by pressing the right 2s. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your formula is wrong.

First you need to calculate press_time in seconds for 1 degree: `2/360` (assuming that it takes 2 seconds to rotate by 360 degrees).
Then, you can get duration of button pressing **in seconds** for certain angle by multiplying angle by that constant (remember: `time.sleep` accepts seconds as an argument):

```
press_time = angle * (2/360)

pyautogui.keyDown('right')
time.sleep(press_time)
pyautogui.keyDown('up')
```

Also, calculate press_time **before** pressing down, since calculation of press_time takes a little bit of time, and button will be pressed all the time while python doing his calculations.

Comment: I see, let try this,   In addition, how can I simulate 'press the right mouse button + move the mouse'?

Comment: @k000x [pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html)?

Comment: As far as the above code , after testing, I found that it will still exceed 360 degrees after 2 seconds, Is it because the game itself might not be 2s/360?